# Can I use time.sleep while printing a couple of sentences in Python

Tags: python-3.x, printing, sleep

I'm printing 2/3 at a same print() command. But I want to use sleep at some points. Like this:

```
print("Hello world!")
time.sleep(1)
print ("I just stopped for 1 sec!!")
time.sleep(1)
print (" But I want to Marge these lines. How?")
```

To this or something like that:

```
print ("Hello world!",time.sleep(1),"I just stopped for 1 sec!!",time.sleep(1)," But I want to Marge these lines. How?")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `end` to prevent the `print` from adding a newline and make sure to `flush` the statement to force it to print before continuing.

```
import time

print("Hello world!", end=" ", flush=True)
time.sleep(1)
print ("I just stopped for 1 sec!!", end=" ", flush=True)
time.sleep(1)
print ("But I want to Marge these lines. How?")
```

Output:

```
Hello world! I just stopped for 1 sec!! But I want to Marge these lines. How?
```